# Backbone collection from Json file and cache on localstorage

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I am relatively new in the backbone library. I'm trying to build a mobile application based on backbone + requirejs + jquery-mobile. I can fill my collection with existing json local file. (in the future may come from a remote server). 
Now I'm trying to get this collection to be called only once and then storing it in localStorage for read. for this I am trying to use this adapter (https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) but I do not understand how.

### Sample code

```
// models
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  var AzModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      item: '',
      img:"img/gi.jpg"
    },
    initialize: function(){
    }
  });
  return AzModel;
});

// Collection
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'models/az'], function($, _, Backbone, AzModel) {
    var AzCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("AzStore"), // Unique name within your app.       
    url : "json/azlist.json",
    model : AzModel
    parse : function(response) {
         return response;
    }
});

return AzCollection;
});

define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'collections/azlist', 'text!templates/karate/az.html'], function($, _, Backbone, AzList, AzViewTemplate) {
    var AzView = Backbone.View.extend({
        id:"az",
        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new AzList(); 
            var self = this;
            this.collection.fetch().done(function() {
                //alert("done")
                self.render();
            }); 

        },
        render : function() {
            var data = this.collection;
            if (data.length == 0) {
                // Show's the jQuery Mobile loading icon
                $.mobile.loading("show");
            } else {
                 $.mobile.loading("hide");
                console.log(data.toJSON());
                  this.$el.html(_.template(AzViewTemplate, {data:data.toJSON()}));
                  // create jqueryui
                 $(document).trigger("create");
            }
            return this;
        }
    });
    return AzView;
});
```

Does someone can point me the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Backbone local storage adapter overrides `Collection.sync`, the function which is used when you `fetch` the collection, or `save` models within the collection. If you set the `Collection.localStorage` property, it redirects the calls to the local storage instead of the server. This means you can have either or -- read and write to local storage or server -- but not both at the same time.

This leaves you two options:

1. Do the initial `fetch`, which populates the data from the server, and only then set the localStorage property:

   ```
   var self = this;

   self.collection.fetch().done(function() {
       self.collection.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("AzStore");
       self.render();
   });
   ```
2. Set the `Collection.localStorage` property as you do now, and fetch the initial dataset manually using `Backbone.ajaxSync`, which is the alias given to `Backbone.sync` by the localstorage adapter:

   ```
   Backbone.ajaxSync('read', self.collection).done(function() {
       self.render();
   }
   ```

The latter option might be preferrable, because it doesn't prevent you from loading the data from the server later on, if required.

You could quite neatly wrap the functionality as a method on the collection:

```
var AzCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('AzStore'),
    refreshFromServer: function() {
        return Backbone.ajaxSync('read', this);    
    }    
});
```

When you want to load data from the server, you can call that method:

```
collection.refreshFromServer().done(function() { ... });
```

And when you want to use the local storage, you can use the native `fetch`:

```
collection.fetch().done(function() { ... });
```

**Edited** to correct mistake in sample code for the benefit of drive-by googlers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I saw an updated localStorage plugin that lets you save to either, I'm going to try and find a link.

Comment: OK I found what I was referring to, it's [backbone.offline](https://github.com/Ask11/backbone.offline) (I haven't used it myself I just remembered reading about it).

Comment: thanks for your reply Fencliff. 've Helped me a lot.
I am implementing the second option "refreshFromServer" but when I call this method, I have an error "The 'url' property or function must be specified."
Any idea why this happen?
  Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the link @jack. I'll take a look to see if it helps

Comment: @Sandcar, the collection must have a url property on order for Backbone to know where to ask for the data. See docs.

Comment: Fencliff, when I saw this error "The url property or function ..." I tried to figure, where the problem might lie.
I googled and Also try to find an answer on docs.
In the example code I am setting the url property in the collection (path to a local Json file for now).
i now that I'm missing something (probably simple) but I can not get there.
  Thanks for your patience

Comment: For those who need more info please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277010/backbone-js-and-local-storage-a-url-property-or-function-must-be-specified) too.
Many thanks to @fencliff for all the effort in pointing the right way

Comment: hey this is good way, but i guess it even after fetching from server we declare localstorage but its size still remains 0, as the fetched data does not gets populated into localstorage