# Backbone collection fetch not firing

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, aura.js

I'm new to backbone and I'm trying to send and receive data from the server in Json format. It just won't work. Here's my code (BTW, I'm using backbone aura):

Collection

```
define(['sandbox', '../models/message'], function(sandbox, Message) {
'use strict';

var Messages = sandbox.mvc.Collection({
    model: Message,
    url: '/messagelist.php',
    localStorage: new sandbox.data.Store('messages-backbone-require'),
    parse: function(response){
        return response.rows;
    }
});

return Messages;

});
```

Model

```
define(['sandbox'], function(sandbox) {
'use strict';

var Message = sandbox.mvc.Model({

    defaults: {
        opened: '',
        messageid: '',
        phonenumber: '',
        numbername: '',
        text: ''
    },
    parse: function(data){
        return data;
    }

});

return Message;
});
```

View

```
define(['sandbox', '../models/message', 'text!../templates/incoming_messages.html'], function(sandbox, Message, incomingMessagesTemplate) {
'use strict';

var AppView = sandbox.mvc.View({
    widgetTemplate: sandbox.template.parse(incomingMessagesTemplate),

    events: {
        'click .refresh': 'refresh'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.widgetTemplate);
        sandbox.events.bindAll(this);
        this.collection.bind('createMessageList', this.createMessageList);
    },

    createMessageList: function() {
        // Will work with the received data here
    },

    render: function() {
        var handle = 'h4';
        this.$el.draggable({handle: handle});
        this.createMessageList();
    },

    refresh: function() {
        this.createMessageList();
    }


});

return AppView;

});
```

Main

```
define(['sandbox', './views/app', './collections/messages'], function(sandbox, AppView, Messages) {
'use strict';

return function(options) {
    var messages = new Messages();

    new AppView({
        el: sandbox.dom.find(options.element),
        collection: messages
    }).render();

    messages.fetch({
        data: {
            type: 'incoming',
            offset: 0,
            offsetcount: 25
        },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function() {
            console.log(messages.models); // Shows an empty array.
        }
    });
};
});
```

I've check logs and it seems that the ajax request (collection.fetch()) is not firing or is not able to communicate with the server. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the Backbone.LocalStorage plugin. When you assign `Collection.localStorage`, the plugin takes over the `fetch` command and reads the data from local storage instead of the server.

See my [answer in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071203/backbone-collection-from-json-file-and-cache-on-localstorage/14071484#14071484) on some options on how to solve this.

Comment: Doesn't the local storage plugin actually take over `Backbone.sync` rather than `fetch`? But that's just nit picking.

Comment: @muistooshort, yessir, OP's question is about `fetch` not firing, and without knowing whether he knows how `sync` works, the most straightforward way of explaining the cause is to cut some corners. The nitty gritty about `sync` override is explained in the linked answer.