# Backbone.js and local storage . A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, local-storage

I'm improving my knowledge about Backbone.js and have this code sample taken from a tutorial. (http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/understanding-backbone-js-simple-example/)

This example will not access the server for now, so to simulate the retrieval of data from the server I have a file name movies.json.

What I am trying to do:

- Add json data in local storage (using localStorage adapter)
- For this I am using Backbone.ajaxSync, Which Is Given to the alias Backbone.sync by the localStorage adapter: I created the method refreshFromServer () to do this
- The reason for doing this is that I'm trying to implement a way to get data only one time (and only refresh when i need to)

My issues:
  I'm having an error "**Uncaught Error: 'url' property or function must be specified**" when I call refreshFromServer (). 
I do not understand why because I set  the url collection. (url : "scripts/data/movies.json" )

Sample code

```
var Theater = {
    Models : {},
    Collections : {},
    Views : {},
    Templates : {}
}

Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({})
Theater.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Theater.Models.Movie,
    localStorage : new Backbone.LocalStorage("MovieStore"), // Unique name within your app.
    url : "scripts/data/movies.json",
    refreshFromServer : function() {
        return Backbone.ajaxSync.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    initialize : function() {
        console.log("Movies initialize")
    }
});

Theater.Templates.movies = _.template($("#tmplt-Movies").html())

Theater.Views.Movies = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $("#mainContainer"),
    template : Theater.Templates.movies,

    initialize : function() {

        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },

    render : function() {
        console.log("render")
        console.log(this.collection.length);

    }
})

Theater.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        "" : "defaultRoute"
    },

    defaultRoute : function() {
        console.log("defaultRoute");
        Theater.movies = new Theater.Collections.Movies()
        new Theater.Views.Movies({
            collection : Theater.movies
        });
        Theater.movies.refreshFromServer();
        //Theater.movies.fetch();
        console.log(Theater.movies.length)
    }
})

var appRouter = new Theater.Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

**Notes:**

- If a comment localStorage property in the collection

  Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({})
  Theater.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model : Theater.Models.Movie,
      //localStorage : new Backbone.LocalStorage("MovieStore")
      ...
  });

  and then in router call normal fetch method

  Theater.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes : {
          "" : "defaultRoute"
      },

  ```
  defaultRoute : function() {

      Theater.movies = new Theater.Collections.Movies()
      new Theater.Views.Movies({
          collection : Theater.movies
      });
      //Theater.movies.refreshFromServer();
      Theater.movies.fetch();
  }
  ```

  })

I can see the json list correctly in my view

- If I use the localStorage property in the collection and then call the standard fetch () method, I see only an empty list (I think it is normal as it is read from the local storage and is empty)
- The error only occurs when using the method refreshFromServer () witch use Backbone.ajaxSync (alias for backbone.sync)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Err... my bad. The `refreshFromServer` implementation is from my answer to your [earlier question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071203/backbone-collection-from-json-file-and-cache-on-localstorage), and it's completely, uselessly wrong.*

`Backbone.sync` expects arguments `(method, model, options)`, but as it stands, it doesn't get what it needs from `refreshFromServer` because the refresh method simply sends forward whatever `arguments` it gets. Sorry for the mistake.

The correct, working implementation would be:

```
refreshFromServer : function(options) {
    return Backbone.ajaxSync('read', this, options);
}
```

It can be used either via `success` / `error` callbacks passed to the `options` hash:

```
this.collection.refreshFromServer({ success: function() { /* refreshed... */ });
```

Or via the jqXHR Promise API:

```
this.collection.refreshFromServer().done(function() { /* refreshed... */ })
```

Or not signing up for callbacks and waiting for the collection `reset` event like in your example:

```
this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
this.collection.refreshFromServer();
```

This should work. Please let me know if it doesn't. I fixed my answer in the previous question too, in case someone stumbles onto it.

**Edit:** To save the data to local storage after refreshing you need to manually `save` each of the models:

```
var collection = this.collection;
collection.refreshFromServer({success: function(freshData) {
    collection.reset(freshData);
    collection.each(function(model) {
        model.save();
    });
}});
```

Comment: thank you so much @ fencliff
I tried the way you say and now I no longer have the error "The" url "property ..." (Which is good :)).

But now when I call refreshFromServer () I have an empty list.
When using Chrome console i notice:
- Json file that is properly called
- Local storage is created but without any key / value

a question: when the json is returned is this automatically placed in localStorage ?

I tried your suggestion in this code example and also in my previous question.

Comment: @Sandcar - the local storage is not automatically populated. You have to `.save()` each model in the collection. I edited my answer, see above.

Comment: now i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object]... has no method 'each' " . It returns my json objects but the collection but I can not iterate over the collection. 

Once again, thanks for your patience

Comment: To get a reference to the collection in the callback, use the `success` callback as per my edit.

Comment: still the same problem in my previous post. I think it's because on the return callback the collection is not a collection of models but a raw javascript array, and does not have an each function. So a try anoher way. **See my edit in your previous answer**. can you check if this is the right approach ? Thanks

Comment: @Sandar, yes, you're right. See my last, and hopefully final edit. It seems I still wasn't paying enough attention. Also please note that if your new data doesn't have some models that are in the local storage, this won't automatically clear them.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm! I'll add a comment in my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071203/backbone-collection-from-json-file-and-cache-on-localstorage) with a link to here in case someone stumbles onto a similiar problem and need help. thank you very much!

Comment: You guys rock! I've had this same issue in a backbone app that I'm working on, and this was spot on! many thanks